# FB graph api: search posts and status updates

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to know if theres a way to search for posts/status updates similar to twitters "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=...".

Thanks

Comment: Answer: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=...&type=post

Comment: Is it also possible to filter the status updates per country level? For example: display ALL public available updates on a country level

Answer (score 2):

Facebook graph api [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) has a whole section dedicated to searching.  To search for publicly available posts, use this format:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=query&type=post

And replace query with the text you want to search for.  You can test this with the facebook [graph api explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=search?q=query&type=post).  This currently doesn't require an access token, but you could include one anyways in case Facebook later requires one.